# ASP.NET MVC - Routing doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am practicing ASP.NET MVC using vs 2013, and writed a simple project, with one controller and view.

controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ShowMyHome()
    {
        return View("MyHome");
    }
}
```

"MyHome" view Code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        Welcome my first MVC page
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

RouteConfig code:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Home",
              url: "Home",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowMyHome", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );
        }
    }
```

when i run and set url line on "http://mySite/Home/ShowMyHome", it works well.
but when i run and set url line on "http://mySite/Home", i get a error:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

It looks like the "Home" routing doesn't work.

Comment: I'd recommend using Phil Haack's Route Debugger. https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/. Do you have a view named index?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Home` route isn't being reached because when navigating to `~/Home` the default route is matched, given that your controller name is `HomeController`.

If your desired result is to map `~/Home` to `ShowMyHome()` explicitly then you will need to move your custom route above the default one.

You don't need to define a separate route for each controller actions you create, 9 times out of 10, the default route is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't routing, it's that ASP.NET can't find your `Index.cshtml` view. You need to add a view for Index().

Answer (score 2):

You still have the default route pointing to the 'Index' view and action, which doesn't exist. Place your custom route before the default route and your problem should be solved.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Home",
          url: "Home",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowMyHome", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Home",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowMyHome", id =UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a view for Index. In the Controller, right-click on Index() and choose "Add View".

Then, complete the wizard for how you want that view to behave.

Edit: Based on the answers I'm seeing, I believe there may be a small misunderstanding. You should not need to create a new route for every Controller you make. You should generally use the default route and use Index as your home page. Custom routes tend to come into play when you need to provide more information to your controller than just /action/id.

Comment: I added a view. now i dont get a error, but just a blank page, not the "Welcome my first MVC page" string that i get when i set "http://mySite/Home/ShowMyHome" in the url.

Comment: For Index or for ShowMyHome? You need to have a View for each ActionResult in your controller that you wish to link to. By default, your route is set to "Index" (most projects are configured this way by default), which means that you need to have a View specifically for Index. Check your Views folder, under Home subfolder. You should have at least two *.cshtml files - ShowMyHome.cshtml and Index.cshtml.

Comment: To share that HTML, put it in the shared View. Each View will have differing Razor code that is specific to that method on the Controller.